# How to Add Ubuntu Repo in Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, repository, gpg

My Question is how to add Ubuntu repository in Debian I mean you can't execute

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

in Debian you can just add its full link or edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or add file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` but it'll ask you about GPG Signature and it's really hard to do it.
So, is there a way to add Ubuntu shell features in Debian or at least an easy way to perform signature keys step.
because I'm really stuck at some commands like `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/screenfetch` I mean where's the link in this case
and not every PPA have a launchpad webpage.

Comment: You can't: Debian isn't Ubuntu

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the comments, [you shouldn’t add Ubuntu repositories to Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). You *will* end up breaking your system if you go down this path.

If you want Ubuntu, run Ubuntu; don’t try to take pieces of it and add them to Debian.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add any repository. `screenfetch` is available on debian just run `sudo apt install screenfetch`. Adding Ubuntu repository will break Debian.